# Youtube API: Adding videos to a playlist with the new 32 character playlist ID

Tags: python, youtube-api, playlist

I've been struggling with what I thought would be a simple task: Adding a video to a youtube playlist. I've got the uri and video id, so this should work, right?

```
uri = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/dolkarr/playlists/AAnCXJ-nfQZwZYqo69euVZVyJ_XofIJs"
vid = "dmoDLyiQYKw"

video = yt_service.AddPlaylistVideoEntryToPlaylist(uri, vid)
```

But it returns this error response:

> gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 400, 'body': 'Invalid request URI', 'reason': 'Bad Request'}

After a bit of research, I found out that it only works for the 16 character playlist IDs which some of my older playlists have. Prefixing "PL" makes no difference.
Someone "solved" the problem by using a playlist ID that doesn't contain "-", but I am unable to create such a playlist! All of them start with `AAnCXJ-nfQ`...

So, all I'm asking... is there any possibility to make this work? Either by somehow creating a playlist with old-style ID or making it accept these... I need to create several playlists with 200 videos each and I really don't want to fill them all manually... Thanks for response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uri = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/dolkarr/playlists/AAnCXJ-nfQZwZYqo69euVZVyJ_XofIJs"

you should remove **user/userid**, become

uri = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/AAnCXJ-nfQZwZYqo69euVZVyJ_XofIJs"

Check it out: https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python#AddVideoToPlaylist

Comment: oh... Thanks! I swear I tried that before and it didn't work. Must have done something wrong. Still, it seems strange that it works for the shorter IDs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the best result, I'd suggest you to use Data API v3

There is a great Python example that accomplished what you are trying to do.
'https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert#examples'

This should get you started really quick.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best practice is always use the prefix PL:

from this article:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/playlists-now-with-more-pl.html

*While we will continue to support using unprefixed playlist IDs as metadata or in API request URLs for the time being, at some point in the future we may require the “PL” prefix to be used whenever a playlist ID is provided. We’ll provide additional guidance if we do decide to stop supporting requests with unprefixed playlist IDs.*

but problems have been reported

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/0c6dorRZ7bg

I believe that if you use the PL prefix and you get an error, then you must report a possible bug