# Adding youtube video to playlist using YouTube Data API v3 in Python

Tags: python, youtube-api

I want to create a script to add a youtube video into playlist in my channel using YouTube Data API v3. I tried with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228815/adding-youtube-video-to-playlist-using-python) and wrote this code with help of example code given [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python)

```
    import httplib2
    import os
    import sys

    from apiclient.discovery import build
    from apiclient.errors import HttpError
    from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
    from oauth2client.file import Storage
    from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run


    # The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
    # the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
    # client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
    # the Google Cloud Console at
    # https://cloud.google.com/console.
    # Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
    # For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
    #   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
    # For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
    #   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets

    CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

    # This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
    # missing.
    MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
    WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

    To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
    found at:

    %s

    with information from the Cloud Console
    https://cloud.google.com/console

    For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
    https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
    """ % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                               CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

    # This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
    # authenticated user's account.
    YOUTUBE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
    YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
    YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"


    def get_authenticated_service():
        flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scope=YOUTUBE_SCOPE,
        message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

        storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
        credentials = storage.get()

        if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
            credentials = run(flow, storage)

        return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
            http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


    def add_video_to_playlist(youtube,videoID,playlistID):
      add_video_request=youtube.playlistItem().insert(
      part="snippet",
      body={
            'snippet': {
              'playlistId': playlistID, 
              'resourceId': {
                      'kind': 'youtube#video',
                  'videoId': videoID
                }
            #'position': 0
            }
    }
).execute()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
     youtube = get_authenticated_service()
         add_video_to_playlist(youtube,"yszl2oxi8IY","PL2JW1S4IMwYubm06iDKfDsmWVB-J8funQ")
```

but I am getting error that I am not able to figure out

```
    alok@alok:~/exp/python/youtube$ python playlist.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "playlist.py", line 83, in <module>
        add_video_to_playlist(youtube,"yszl2oxi8IY","PL2JW1S4IMwYubm06iDKfDsmWVB-J8funQ")
      File "playlist.py", line 67, in add_video_to_playlist
        add_video_request=youtube.playlistItem().insert(
    AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'playlistItem'
```

could anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The method is "playlistItems()" (with an "s")

(I'm assuming your indentation is only wrong here question, and not in your actual code)

Answer (score 0):

code is correct, there is only spelling mistake. `playlistItem()` should be `playlistItems()`

correct code is:

```
    import httplib2
    import os
    import sys

    from apiclient.discovery import build
    from apiclient.errors import HttpError
    from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
    from oauth2client.file import Storage
    from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run


    # The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
    # the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
    # client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
    # the Google Cloud Console at
    # https://cloud.google.com/console.
    # Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
    # For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
    #   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
    # For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
    #   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets

    CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

    # This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
    # missing.
    MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
    WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

    To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
    found at:

    %s

    with information from the Cloud Console
    https://cloud.google.com/console

    For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
    https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
    """ % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                               CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

    # This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
    # authenticated user's account.
    YOUTUBE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
    YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
    YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"


    def get_authenticated_service():
        flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scope=YOUTUBE_SCOPE,
        message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

        storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
        credentials = storage.get()

        if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
            credentials = run(flow, storage)

        return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
            http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


    def add_video_to_playlist(youtube,videoID,playlistID):
      add_video_request=youtube.playlistItem().insert(
      part="snippet",
      body={
            'snippet': {
              'playlistId': playlistID, 
              'resourceId': {
                      'kind': 'youtube#video',
                  'videoId': videoID
                }
            #'position': 0
            }
    }
     ).execute()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
     youtube = get_authenticated_service()
         add_video_to_playlist(youtube,"yszl2oxi8IY","PL2JW1S4IMwYubm06iDKfDsmWVB-J8funQ")
```