# Cannot get authentication with google api from python script to work - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I am trying to create a trivial python script that allows me to bulk add a list of youtube videos to a playlist of mine.

The problem I am having is getting this script to get authenticated to the google api with my apps credentials.

I am basically just using the sample authentication script at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python
and this stackoverflow question ([Adding youtube video to playlist using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228815/adding-youtube-video-to-playlist-using-python))

The main stopping point is that I keep getting an Error: `redirect_uri_mismatch`. Since I am calling the script from the commandline on my laptop, the error is saying: `The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:8080/ did not match a registered redirect URI.`

I have set `http://localhost:8080` as the **JavaScript origins** and `http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback` as the **Redirect URIs**

And i am using the following (as run from the python shell):

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow
import argparse, sys, os

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('path to my CLIENT_SECRETS.json file', scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube')
store = Storage('config/%s-oauth2.json' % sys.argv[0])
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser])
flags = parser.parse_args()
credentials = run_flow(flow, store, flags)
```

then the terminal opens my browser and in the browser I get the 400 error. The following gets printed to the terminal:

> Your browser has been opened to visit:
>
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=my-CLIENT-ID&access_type=offline
>
> If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
>   application with the command-line parameter 
>    --noauth_local_webserver

I am not sure what I am really supposed to be putting as the redirect URIs and javascript origins, but I don't intend to run this anywhere else other than as a python script from the terminal of my laptop. The documentation provides `https://example.com/` and `https://example.com/oauth2callback` as pre populated values, but clearly that's not where I am running this "app" from and I know that's just placeholder stuff.

**UPDATE**: not sure why, but i realize that the url the app is sending me to has the redirect_uri parameter set to just `http://localhost:8080/`, if i add oauth2callback to the uri than i get sent to the screen where it asks me to accept management of the youtube account. so that's odd.

**UPDATE 2**: and if I change my redirect uris to just `http://localhost:8080/` via the developer console, i can get my credentials, but I am sure this is not the best way to be going about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just running this through you terminal than you can use the native host by creating a client ID as an installed app and then selecting other.  If you are trying to do this using the web app client ID and only want it to be local then you would use these:

JavaScript origins: http://localhost:your_port_here/

Redirect URIs:  http://localhost:your_port_here/url_path
where url_path is the place you want google to send you after authentication.

Edit: the tutorial code only works if you are using a native app. If you are indeed planning to create a web app there are separate instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The `redirect_uri` parameter set to just http://localhost:8080/ is by design. When you call `tools.run_flow()` it is spinning up a server of it's own behind the scenes and initiating the oauth flow. It is then expecting the `redirect_uri` to redirect back to the server it spun up (which is listening on port 8080) so that it can use the `access_token` it receives to create the credentials and put them in storage.